# nested router with lazy load not work propertly

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I am new to Vue and want to navigate `Product` child routes, but it do not work & get `NotFound` page instead. 
So my question is how to make it properly.
Or can someone give some details. Thanks

[Online Editor](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-router-test-m8c0s)

`index.js`

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/products',
    component: () => import('../views/ProductPage.vue'),
    children: productRouter
  },
  {
    path: '/**',
    component: NotFound
  }
]
```

`product.js`

```
const productRouter = [
  {
    path: '',
    name: 'products',
    component: ProductPage
  },
  {
    path: 'product/:id',
    name: 'ProductDetails',
    component: ProductDetails
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: NotFound
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some little mistakes leading to your unexpected result.

In `product.js` router you should not prefix again with `products` since it is already in the scope of the `/products` route. The `NotFound` route is also not needed in this definition since the parent's `NotFound` already matches the same route patterns. You can rewrite the product router definition like below :

```
const productRouter = [
  {
    path: ':id',
    name: 'ProductDetails',
    component: ProductDetails
  }
]
```

Then, in `ProductList.vue`, you should rewrite your `router-link` as below :

```
<router-link :to="`/products/${item.id}`"> {{ item.description }} </router-link>
```

Finally, in `ProductPage.vue`, you are missing the `<router-view></router-view>` needed to render your child routes as explained in the [vue router documentation.](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html). You could rewrite it like below :

```
<template>
  <div id="productPage">
    <h1>This is an Product Page</h1>

    <ProductList :items="products"> </ProductList>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```